# Mongo Db issues with disk space

Tags: mongodb

Is there any way we can compress mongodb data which is saved on the disk ? 
Currently the data saved is taking more than 30 Gb .

Any help is appreciated .

Thanks 
Sanchet

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data on disk in mongodb is dependent on the data model you have chosen. If most of your data is embedded(de-normalized) then obviously it will lead to higher space consumption on disk. Infact MongoDB advocates that since disk space is cheap we can easily afford to duplicate data for better performance.

Also, you can archive data that is not being used frequently.
Additional tip - You can limit the size of Journal files if they are consuming lot of disk space.

Answer (score 0):

if you could provide a litle bit more information about what Data is stored we may can help you a litle better. I would guess that an easy compress is not possible, because its already stored in a binary format (well okay, from time to time it uses more space than a simple binary format because of special functions). But to compress that and still have it available... I dont think so.

But what you could do if you save a lot of the same data as nested documents is that you save this data in an extra collection and refer to it over the ObjectId... But this would also mean a change in the software which works with the DB...

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution called TokuMX (http://www.tokutek.com/products/tokumx-for-mongodb/), it replaces the default storage system and add compression (you can even choose your compression algorithm). You can reduce your storage space by 90%. That works quite well and its completely reliable (but it's not yet available for windows).

Answer (score 0):

You have two options: repairDatabase or compact. repairDatabase will cause downtime but will compress all collections in the entire database. Compact will run continuously on a per collection basis.

Reference: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/repairDatabase/